# BBCode preg_replace change link with or without "http://"

Tags: php

I'm working on a parser for my site and I've run into an issue--Is there anyway to remove/insert "http://" from a string user preg_replace? I know the basics of how to use the function, and have been following tutorials, but I'm not exactly sure how to go about doing this.

here's my code:

```
    function showBBcodes($text) 
{   
    // BBcode array
    $find = array(
    '~\[b\](.*?)\[/b\]~s',
    '~\[i\](.*?)\[/i\]~s',
    '~\[u\](.*?)\[/u\]~s',
    '~\[quote\](.*?)\[/quote\]~s',
    '~\[size=(.*?)\](.*?)\[/size\]~s',
    '~\[color=(.*?)\](.*?)\[/color\]~s',
    '~\[url=([^]]*)\]([^[]*)\[/url\]~s',
    '~\[img\](https?://.*?\.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp))\[/img\]~s'
    );
    // HTML tags to replace BBcode
    $replace = array(
    '<b>$1</b>',
    '<i>$1</i>',
    '<span style="text-decoration:underline;">$1</span>',
    '<pre>$1</'.'pre>',
    '<span style="font-size:$1px;">$2</span>',
    '<span style="color:$1;">$2</span>',
    '<a href="https://$1">$2\</a>',
    '<img src="$1" alt="" />'
    );

    // Replacing the BBcodes with corresponding HTML tags
    return preg_replace($find,$replace,$text);
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the [bbcode extension](http://php.net/bbcode)?

Comment: What? The PHP website may be a little dry, but it is certainly not difficult to use. I do not understand what you mean about the comment section. It is just a section containing some comments...

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen I mean what I mean... The comment section isn't defined well, or at least it wasn't last time I looked on the site last. It would bleed into the main documentation of whatever i was looking at (preg_replace was the worst). So I don't use their website. I didn't say it was difficult to use, i said it was cluttered and not useful to me.

Comment: Are you not able to ignore the comments? Would it help if the comments were hidden from view, by default? I can see how they can be a little too much.

Comment: Can you not remove `https://` from the `$replace` array, and instead put it in the `$find` array? Something like `'~\[url=(https?://[^\]]+)\]([^\[]*)\[/url\]~s'`.

Comment: No--it's not that i'm unable to ignore the comments, its that the comments have no disconnect from the rest of the document. I could give a rats ass about the comments, until I'm scrolling down and think i'm reading a part of the official documentation, only to realize I'm reading a comment from someone who doesn't know substr from str_replace. The comments are the documentation look exactly the same and there's no spacing between them on my screen.